# Emulator won't start because of Gradle

Tags: gradle, flutter

Totally new to Flutter and Android Studio here, so please bear with my ignorance.

I am running Zorin OS (yes, it's awesome) and I have installed Flutter , apparently properly and here is my Flutter Doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I have also set up a a nexus and a pixel emulators and connected my phone, all seem to load just fine.

The only thing is, when I hit that "play" button to test an app, I get this error message:

```
Wrong full snapshot version, expected '20e5c4f7dc44368ac5a17643b93665f6' found '481077be32626176580fa89c1db7e085'

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/tarek/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/tarek/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have added --debug, --stacktrace --scan as I have seen usually recommended in previous threads, still nothing changes.

Could someone please walk me through fixing this?

Thank you

Comment: 0. use `flutter clean` in the project root folder and try again.
1. Check if sufficient RAM is available to gradle in `project_root/android/gradle.properties`
2. If that doesn't work then delete `.gradle` folder in `home` and let the sdk get the version it needs. Note THIS REQUIRES  INTERNET CONNECTION; nearly 200mb download depending upon gradle version.

Comment: With updating of your android studio and the gradle , your emulator is updated. After that , do 'wipe' for each emulator and then remove all your created emulator items.Then restart android studio and add new emulator. If your connection with google is not established for getting the updates, please use a vpn for proper connecting

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, but running "flutter clean" and deleting .Gradle didn't go the trick for me.   How can I check RAM? Sorry I didn't get it, is that a terminal command?

Comment: @Maniaq, I have removed the emulators and downloading them over again. That also didn't help.

Comment: Of course for releasing memory you could use invalidate and restarting android studio(I think you experiment this).I countered many times with this issue.The first and important solution was that I told . And the second solution is doing first solution then close all programs and restart your computer.

Comment: I decided to remove everything and install from scratch. Now it works fine. Thank you guys.